# GWT 2.7 with Rest

Tags: rest, gwt, weblogic12c, intellij-14, gwt-super-dev-mode

We are building a project and will be using gwt 2.7 with rest ( spring) and weblogic server.
The problem which we face is that I want to run the gwt module on superdev mode (which runs on 8888 port by default) but the rest is deployed on 7001 port on weblogic server.
I cannot call the rest services from superdev mode as it gives a cross site scripting error.

How can get my super dev mode running so that I can test and develop UI and connect to rest services on different port.
I know there has been topic on use a different server for dev mode. But i don't see any examples.

Can some please suggest wat needs to be done. Even if it requires changing the project structure to get the dev mode working with rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem for web-development. It can be solved by using:

1. [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (at the REST server)
2. Using a [proxy servlet](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet) (I use this approach, but with a handwritten servlet)
3. Disable the browser security (I would not do this)

Answer (score 0):

did you try running GWT module on external server mode?

[image]